# ERC 20 Token transferFrom isn't working in my smart contract. Doesn't throw any Exception either

Tags: reactjs, solidity, smartcontracts, matic, web3-react

I wrote a contract in Solidity with the following task in mind:

- The user approves the smart contract to transfer a certain amount of tokens from their wallet.
- The smart contract uses this amount to transfer to an address given as a parameter. But it also takes 1 token from this amount to transfer to the developer of the contract.
- If everything succeeds, the user receives a "Payment successful!" message.

The first step (the approval) was made using React and Web3:

```
const derc20contract = '0x36850b80ad73fe66216609B9796ed6ceae8BE29F';
const handleClick = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const prtmp = await detectEthereumProvider();
            
            // -------------------- Approve Part ------------------------------// 
            const web3 = new Web3(prtmp);
            const erc20contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
                erc20abi, 
                derc20token,
                { from: '0xFromAddress' }
            );

            await erc20contract.methods.approve(derc20contract, web3.utils.toHex(3e18)).send();
            // ---------------------------------------------------------------//

            const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(derc20abi, derc20contract);
            const response = await contract.methods.send_usdt(
                '0xToAddress',
                web3.utils.toHex(3e18)
            )
            .call({ from: '0xFromAddress'});
            console.log(response);
    };
```

Once the approval succeeds the second part of the function resolves. The contract I deployed has a function called `send_usdt`. Through this function is my smart contract able to transfer the amount approved.

```js
/ SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external returns(bool);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _contract) external returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address _buyer) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address _contract,  uint tokens) external returns (bool);
}

contract DPortalSubscription {

    address private owner;
    mapping(address => uint32) subscription_fees;
    
    constructor()
    { 
        owner = msg.sender; 
    }

    function check_balance() external view returns (uint256)
    {
        // TestToken ( Plasma Bridge ) in Mumbai Network 
        IERC20 usdt = IERC20(address(0xfe4F5145f6e09952a5ba9e956ED0C25e3Fa4c7F1));
        uint256 balance = usdt.balanceOf(msg.sender);
        return balance;
    }

    function check_sender_address() external view returns (address)
    {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function check_allowance()external returns(uint256)
    {
        // TestToken ( Plasma Bridge ) in Mumbai Network 
        IERC20 usdt = IERC20(address(0xfe4F5145f6e09952a5ba9e956ED0C25e3Fa4c7F1));
        uint256 allowance = usdt.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        return allowance;
    }

    function send_usdt(address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (string memory)
    {
        // TestToken ( Plasma Bridge ) in Mumbai Network 
        IERC20 usdt = IERC20(address(0xfe4F5145f6e09952a5ba9e956ED0C25e3Fa4c7F1));
        require(_amount > 1, "Purchases must be higher than 1 usdt");
        require(usdt.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _amount, "The buyer doesn't have enough funds");
        require(usdt.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= _amount, "Permissions to transfer tokens denied");
        require(usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, _to, _amount-1) == true, "Couldn't transfer tokens to seller");
        require(usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, owner, 1) == true, "Couldn't transfer tokens to support");
        return "Payment successful!";  
    }
}
```

Once the second part of the function in React resolves, I receive the confirmation "Payment successful!" But the tokens weren't transferred. I keep the same amount in my "From Wallet", "To Wallet" and "Deploy Wallet" as before.

---

The problem was inside the react snippet. By changing the method `call` to `sell` the money could be successfully transferred.

```js
const response = await contract.methods.send_usdt
(
    '0xToAddress',
    web3.utils.toHex(3e18)
)
.call({ from: '0xFromAddress' });
```

was changed to:

```js
const response = await contract.methods.send_usdt
(
    '0xToAddress',
    web3.utils.toHex(3e18),
    { from: '0xFromAddress' }
)
.send();
```

which worked but raised another question. When I use the previous `call` method, the function returns "Payment Successful!" and with the sell method I receive an Object.

Since "Payment Successful" isn't true, I was wondering if it could be possible to throw an Exception when someone interacts with my contract using the call method.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[answer]" and their linked pages. Please don't summarize solutions in your question. SO pages are separated into a single question section, followed by one or more answers. Don't put solutions in your question. SO isn't a message board, it's more like an online Q/A reference or a cookbook. As such, questions and answers are separate and have to be kept separate. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271399/128421 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267434/128421.

Comment: In addition, please don't use "edit" or "update" tags to mark changes. Simple update the text with the new information as if it'd been there from the beginning. "[Should “Edit:” in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/128421)"
helps explain.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Kuly14's answer and in order to make it clearer, you may want to create the following function instead:

```
function send_usdt(address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (string memory) {
    // TestToken ( Plasma Bridge ) in Mumbai Network 
    IERC20 usdt = IERC20(address(0xfe4F5145f6e09952a5ba9e956ED0C25e3Fa4c7F1));
    require(_amount > 1, "Purchases must be higher than 1 usdt");

    usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, owner, 1);
    usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, _to, _amount-1);

    return "Payment successful!";  
}
```

Notes:

1. By just calling the `transferFrom` method, it will jump its corresponding error if something goes wrong. You do not need to handle them.
2. I have changed the order in which you transfer the tokens. First, I send them to the owner and then to the desired recipient to avoid fees payments problems, but if you prefer the other way round, it is possible.

Comment: Thank you very much NuMa. I changed my code the way you proposed :) I tried the solution from you and Kuly14. Sadly it didn't work. BUT what worked was changing in my react snippet the method 'call' to 'sell'. I will post the solution